# Add title to MSHTA browse method

Tags: vbscript

I was trying to find a way to browse and select a file as a variable using VBScript. The standard methods of using common.dialog were not working thus I used the below:

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE ><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
sFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
```

I would like to be able to add a title to the dialog box that appears, but cannot seem to determine the proper argument to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `input type=file` has a fixed `Choose File to upload` title. I suggest using this little [filedialog.exe](https://github.com/LesFerch/FileDialog) command line tool. Full source code is there if you want to compile your own copy or use the EXE I've provided. Another excellent option is to use [VbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/) to convert your VBS into an EXE and then you can use VbsEdit's file dialog functions. It's $60, but that's a lifetime license. It pays for itself in time saved on day one, as it includes a lot of other extensions in addition to the file dialogs.

Comment: I just updated the [FileDialog](https://lesferch.github.io/FileDialog/) zip file to include a couple of VBS examples.