# How to get batch file to process from within folder its located?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have the below code to process the move of suppression files but its moving from the desktop and not the folder in which the batch file is located.

```
JobNo = InputBox("Input Job Number")
strfolder = InputBox("Input the job name: ex. Monthly Statements, or Brochures")


Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run """C:\TEST\" & JobNo & " " & strfolder & "\Processing\Suppressions.bat"""
```

I just thought that I could also add an echo to the batch file, but I was trying to avoid this if possible. The echo would be CD to the directory where the bat was located.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try setting the current directory in your VBS script with `oWSH.CurrentDirectory = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70043076/15764378).

Comment: And please follow up on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76335080/15764378). Thanks.

Comment: It appears to me as if the first line of your batch file, _(`Suppressions.bat`)_, should be ```@CD /D "%~dp0"```, or ```@PushD "%~dp0"```.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, based upon [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76341490/how-to-get-batch-file-to-process-from-within-folder-its-located#comment134620236_76341490) by [LesFerch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15764378/lesferch), solved my issue!

```
JobNo = InputBox("Input Job Number")
strfolder = InputBox("Input the job name: ex. Monthly Statements, or Brochures")

set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.CurrentDirectory = objFSO.GetParentFolderName("C:\TEST\" & JobNo & " " & strfolder & "\Processing\Suppressions.bat")
objShell.Run """C:\TEST\" & JobNo & " " & strfolder & "\Processing\Suppressions.bat"""
```